# Как прервать повторное срабатывание при скролле setInterval?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, setinterval

```js
function userProgress(time) {
  var start = 0;
  let progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
  time = Math.round(time * 10);
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (start > 100) {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    } else {
      progress.value = start;
    }
    start++;
  }, time);
}

//Вот тут условие при котором срабатывает прогресс бар (setInterval)
window.onmousewheel = e => {
  if (e.offsetY > 450) { //eсли больше то выполняется скрипт
    userProgress(.8)
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#progress {
  margin-top: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100" id="progress"></progress>
```

Comment: Проблема в постоянном срабатывание кода, а надо чтобы код выполнился единожды при скролле и больше не срабатывал до перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Ну самое банальное - булев флаг.

Comment: Ну так вызовите `clearInterval(intervalId)`

Comment: Пробовал не получается, все равно срабатывает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.onmousewheel = e => {
    if(e.offsetY > 450){ //eсли больше то выполняется скрипт
        userProgress(.8);
        window.onmousewheel = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: помогло спс)) и как я не додумался